# Can variable name be same as Function name in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, naming-conventions, shadowing

In the below code lis is an array as well as a function name with same return type (int), I didn't get any error, Can anybody explain what is happening in the background? Why is the compiler not showing an error?

```
int lis( int arr[], int n )  
{  

int lis[n]; 
lis[0] = 1;    
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++ )  
{ 
    lis[i] = 1; 
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++ )   
        if ( arr[i] > arr[j] && lis[i] < lis[j] + 1)  
            lis[i] = lis[j] + 1;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to the variable name!
You can not define a list in a function, dynamically.

you must write your code like this:

```
int lis(int arr[], int n)
{
    int *lis = new int[n];
    lis[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        lis[i] = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (arr[i] > arr[j] && lis[i] < lis[j] + 1)
                lis[i] = lis[j] + 1;
    }
    delete[] lis;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, code source:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-increasing-subsequence-dp-3/